# How to remove the Qbs container from left page of Aosp launcher3

Tags: android, android-source, android-launcher

[How to add custom view in android's JellyBean Launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141113/)
As per the above said in above link,I have added the left page to existing android AOSP launcher3 code , it's look like screenshot.

But always search container(Qbs container) in first screen, How can i remove in first screen and place it in main screen.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEctl.png)

Comment: I am also trying to add a left swipable screen to launcher3, able to add the screen, but this screen does not allow left or right swipe. Did you face this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the search container from the first screen,

```
FrameLayout gBar = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.g_bar);
gBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```